# jQuery SIMPLEST image slider ?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I need a jquery image slider with basic little banner and arrows right and left , like this http://i.imm.io/emEA.jpeg and slide left and right.Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: One calls that a "carousel", and that's what you need to google to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/), it does exactly what you need.

Comment: Man, it's right there: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Defining-The-Number-Of-Visible-Items

Answer (score 0):

```
Go through this it may be helpful
http://www.webdevtuts.net/coding/create-a-full-background-image-slider-using-jquery/#
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/
http://www.elated.com/articles/elegant-sliding-image-gallery-with-jquery
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel
```